# C# Thread Reuse without ThreadPool

Tags: c#, threadpool, reusability

I've got a few instances of the same class. During the classes lifetime, every method call on this class should be executed on the same thread. But for each instance I need a different thread.
I thought about Threadpool, but it seems that I have too less control about it.

How can I reuse a thread without using ThredPool?

Thank you! Martin

Edit (why I need this):
I have to use a win32 dll to access business logic of a third-party product. This dll is not designed for a multi-threaded environment like a web application. When I run my ASP.NET MVC application in ASP Classic Mode (STA Thread), everything works fine so far. But the problem is that all users going to block each other. This component also maintains some state. As soon as a different thread is accessing this component, it will not recognize the connection-handle I have to pass in for each method call. I got the connection handle after a logon procedure. I want to put my web application in MTA mode back again and use a worker-concept, assigning about 10 users to a worker (max. 10 users should block each other). One worker should always use the same thread to execute the api calls so the component will not stubmle. 
I'm not happy with this situation, but I have to find am acceptable solution.

**Update - Found a Solution:**
Thanks to the "Smart Thread Pool" from Ami Bar I could accomplish the behavior I was looking for (easily). For each worker, I have now my own thread pool instance with a max and min number of one thread. Well, it's not the idea of a thread pool, but it makes it very easy to handle the work-items and it also has some nice other featrues. The web application is running on MTA now. 
I'm going to prepare some load tests to see if its stable over hours. 
see here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool

Comment: What is the problem in creating new thread each time OR using thread from thread pool, if thread saves data to object before dieing?

Comment: Why do you need a different thread per object? that doesn't sound hugely scaleable (of course, it could be fine if the number of instances is smallish)

Comment: Do you want to "reuse a thread" or do you "need a different thread"?

Comment: I would like to reuse threads. Just found a possible solution from Ami Bar on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool?msg=1327917#xx1327917xx